# Instalation python IIS

Tags: python, selenium, iis

You have already done all the configuration to implement python in the IIS, but it gives me an error.

[image]

I already installed python 3.9 on my machine and the IIS has everything installed

[image]

Configuration python in IIS:

[image]

This is my first attempt at python. What is going wrong?

Comment: Does this have something to do with [selenium]?

Comment: The python use Selenium for my proyect

Comment: Roll back everything you configured so far, and install HttpPlatformHandler instead, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2019#configure-the-httpplatform-handler It's less likely to give you such errors.